# How to specify individual column formats in astropy.io.ascii.read?

Tags: python, astropy

I have an input file which looks like

```
1 1001 
2 0011 
3 0101
```

When I use

```
data=astropy.io.ascii.read('file.in')
```

then both columns get read as integers, meaning that the leading zeros in the second column disappear. I can in principle work around that, but I would like to know how to customize the reading command so I can specify that the first column should be read as an integer, the second as a string, etc. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you try using a different file format? http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/unified.html So you format the file according to specific rules and then you pass in the appropriate format param. ex: data=Table.read('file.in', format='ascii'). See the link I posted.

Comment: Also, run Table.read.help('ascii') to get detailed help text. Also, see http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/read.htmle

Comment: Try with `delimiter=' '`